# Setting Grails DataSource dynamically at runtime to an in-memory H2 instance

Tags: grails, dynamic, groovy, runtime, datasource

Is there an elegant way to, at runtime, configure a `GrailsDomainClass` to use a DataSource or Connection at runtime?  Ideally, this can simply use a in-memory H2 instance.

Here is my use case example.  I am writing a grails service that needs to use the HQL syntax with domain objects to peform some complex database calculations.  I would like it so that it can run concurrently with each thread using an isolated in-memory H2 instance.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  I know Dynamic DataSource routing might be one place to start, but how is this implemented elegantly in Grails?  I need to avoid setting the instances in configuration files as the in-memory H2 instances need to be created on-the-fly.

I'm at this point right now, but not sure how to configure a domain object to use this connection.

```
def ds = new JdbcDataSource()
ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:dw_1;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dw_1")
ds.setUser("sa")
ds.setPassword("sa")
def conn = ds.getConnection()
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas on how this could possibly be accomplished?

Comment: you might want to check out this: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Switching-GORM-datasource-at-runtime-td1346617.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could try setting additional datasource in config and configure domain classes to use [multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources)  and in runtime change connection settings for that additional in-memory datasource or do not change settings but clear it before using or clear on scheduled basis, or do not clear at all.
For the record: haven't used this feature yet myself.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but how would I go about changing the url of an existing dataSource? e.g. if I define it, how do I retrieve it just to change the url?

Comment: So I think you could [externalise datasource config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970133/externalizing-grails-datasource-configuration) and modify file on runtime and [reload configuration after modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561127/how-can-update-external-config-files-without-rebuild-war-file-in-grails).

Comment: So there is no way to create a dataSource on-the-fly, and then attach said datasource to a grails GORM domain class?

Comment: @ThomasFarvour I have just stumbled upon this question. Have you managed to find a solution to this ? What was the approach you took to solve this ?

Answer (score -1):

One quick way to work this around is by creating a new datasource in DataSource.groovy like this:

```
dataSource_example {
    dbCreate = ""
    dialect = "..."
    driverClassName = "..."
    url = "your_db_url"
    username = "your_username"
    password = "your_password"
    pooled = true
    properties {
        ....
    }
}
```

And then in your `GrailsDomainClass`:

```
public GrailsDomainClass {

    static mapping = {
        datasource "example"
        table name: "grails_domain_class", schema: "schema_one"
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you consider that as a "dynamic" datasource ? It's just a mapping to an additional datasource...

Comment: Like asked in the question, "I'm at this point right now, but not sure how to configure a domain object to use this connection". That's exactly what I've answered, how you can configure a domain class to use a different datasource. You could be using a MySQL or Cassandra or whatever you like for the other domains and H2 in the domain yo need.
Different question interpretations I see...